# Java screen scraping without 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, screen-scraping

Does anyone knows of some basic Java screen scraping examples, which do not use 3rd party libraries?
I'd prefer this to have no dependencies, to avoid problems with customizing the code later in time.

K

Comment: You're going to do all code yourself? Good luck with that, including trying to maintain and get all the bugs from your own code, that have been solved ages ago in freely available libraries.

Comment: Depending on the type of webpages you want to scrape from. It can be quite easy, or very hard if you want a dynamic one.